# Desire2Learn differences between valence api data and website data

Tags: desire2learn, valence

When I log in to D2L via website I (as a student) can see only task assigned to groups I am assigned to. When I try to use Valence API to retrieve those task, I recieve all tasks. It looks like I lost user context with api. When I try to retrieve forum topics via Valence API it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Piotr, this sounds like a potential defect in the API, as the API shouldn't give you access to more information than you're given through the web UI. I will follow up on this with the development group so they're aware, but I would encourage you to report this through your organization's support contact, or your account or partner manager, as a potential defect in the API.

It would be helpful if you list out exactly the call(s) that you're making that you believe aren't functioning properly.